# Can anyone explain the pictograph representation of 巴拉斯 please?

Tags: characters

My understanding so far is that:

- 巴 means a huge snake.
- 拉 means like a crop (wheat) and barn (store house).
- 斯 - this one is hardest to understand as it’s quite ancient.

The word in its entirety means something on the lines of:

> The hope to draw/pull to heaven/present

I am no scholar and my knowledge of Mandarin or Cantonese is very poor.

Comment: 巴拉斯 together is just a transliteration of the surname Barras and can specifically refer to Paul Barras, a French politician in the mid to late seventeen hundreds and early eighteen hundreds. The individual meanings of the characters are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

巴 (u+5df4) originally means "legendary gigantic snake", when it eats an elephant, it looks 3 year to excrete the skeleton of the elephant.

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=巴](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B7%B4)

拉 (u+62c9) originally means "break", it does not mean "like a crops (wheat) and barn"

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=拉](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%8B%89)

斯 (u+65af) originally means "cleave with an ax"

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=斯](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%96%AF)

these these characters have difference meanings now, the above explanation would be correct only in the context of etymology.

well, "巴拉斯" together, sounds similar to your name "bharath"; at least in cantonese. interesting.

have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

@水巷孑蠻's answer has the correct information on 拉 and 斯. However, I'd like to point out that 巴 being a gigantic snake is a traditional explanation that has little evidence supporting it.

---

巴 originally depicted a person in a kneeling position holding something in their hand:

[image]

It is most likely the original character for 把, which originally meant *to grasp something in the hand*. A similar depiction can be seen in the ancient character for 以 (*with* or *using*, as in *doing X with Y* or *using X to do Y*), except that the person is standing:

[image]

This kneeling depiction is also seen in the characters 色 (*facial impression* -> *colour*) and 邑 (*city*).

> 色 was originally a graphical variant of 印 (*press down* -> *print*),
>   and, as seen below, both 色 and 印 originally depicted a person being
>   pressed down by a hand:
>
> [image] [image]
>
> 邑 originally depicted a person kneeling outside a city wall (囗):
>
> [image]

In the end, these characters don't mean anything in your context, as they're just a sound representation of your name as @user3306356 said.

---

### References:

- 黃德寬《古文字譜系疏證》
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 裘錫圭《文字學概要》